# Navicat for MySQL. How to let ordinary user login don't display information_schema?

Tags: mysql, navicat

How can I prevent an ordinary (unprivileged) user, when logged in to MySQL from displaying `information_schema`?

Anybody can see it.

Comment: The information_schema is a system MySQL database. It cannot be hidden.

Answer (score 1):

The information_schema database cannot, itself, be hidden.

As you may know, the information_schema tables are not actually tables with data -- information_schema is an SQL interface for observing data structures in the server, and as such, access to information_schema is essentially harmless, because a user cannot use information_schema to access information the user isn't otherwise able to access.

The information_schema tables are subject to the same security as the objects they describe, so their contents appear to vary based on the permissions of the currently logged-in user.

For example, if a user does not have access to a database called "production" then the information_schema `tables` table and `columns` table will not expose those tables and their columns to that user.